# Как распространять программы с БД?

Tags: база-данных, пакет, дистрибутив

Есть серверная программа под Windows и Linux, обязательной частью которой является БД. Как сделать дистрибутив для такой программы? 
Для ОС Windows можно при установке предложить установить СУБД, для Linux - прописать пакет с СУБД в зависимость. На как добавить пользователя, настроить авторизацию в БД (например, PostgreSQL требует настройки для доступа к ней по логину и паролю), развернуть саму БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы пользуетесь не встроенной СУБД (типа SQLite), то сама СУБД -- это пререквизит. Дистрибутив приложения не должен заниматься установкой СУБД. Это обязанность администратора/пользователя. В инсталляторе же вы спрашиваете адрес сервера, данные для аутентификации и имя базы. Сама БД должна создаваться и настраиваться автоматически с помощью скриптов.